# How does openload.co manage to go into fullscreen mode without warning message on chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

The video hosting site openload.co seems to have found a way to force the browser to go into full screen mode without displaying the usual message on the top of the page (like "www.youtube.com is now full screen. Exit full screen. Allow"). At least on Chrome 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit) on Mac OS X v10.10.5. This doesn't seem to work on firefox and safari.

To demonstrate this I uploaded a video here: https://openload.co/f/88QXNNav4rg/

Just click on the play button. Beware of several pop-ups.

I want to find out how they did it. Just out of curiosity. The way this was implemented is very annoying for the user. I'm aware of this being very bad practise.